# How do I in-system program LPC17XX?

Tags: arm, programming, isp

I plan to buy an [mbed](http://mbed.org/) module to get started with NXP LPC17XX. Developing and downloading code seem the easiest possible. What are my options for in-system programming this code in non-mbed devices? I understand the bootloader only requires a UART connection to my host PC.
What tools are available for Windows PCs? Can they directly work with the object code I created on the mbed site?
Can I use code for the LPC1759 directly on other LPC17XX devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lpc21isp programmer which was originally written for the LPC21xx series but  recent versions also support the LPC17xx series. It requires only a serial port but it is helpful to connect the RESET and ISP pins because they will have to be manipulated to force the chip into the bootloader.

There are binaries for Windows and the code compiles without problems on both Linux and OS X.

PS. There is also JTAG but who would want to use that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [mbed forum](http://mbed.org/forum/mbed)  is the best place for questions like that, it's been answered there. However, mbed binaries can be executed on any target using the same device. [Here](http://mbed.org/users/chris/notebook/prototype-to-hardware/) are the details from the mbed Notebook.

Comment: Leon, thanks for the link, but I'm not sure the question belongs on the mbed forum; it's about programming a device when I _move away_ from mbed.

Comment: this is the place to ask all technical questions. We should not turn people away because their are other options.

Comment: I did point him to the correct answer, though, on the mbed web site. I found it by searching the mbed forum, which he could have done in a few seconds.

Comment: you make it sound as if I'm too lazy too look it up on mbed. I didn't because I didn't expect to find it there, as it doesn't have anything to do with the mbed module; that you program over USB.

Comment: @stevenv: mbed is posed as a prototype module. Naturally they'd want you to use it as a base for production units, and tell exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the LPC17XX series is all the same core, just different peripherals, memory size and clock speeds.  So the code should work, as long as you don't run out of memory, try to use a peripheral that isn't there or have timing dependent code.

You can program the chip via JTAG or its built-in bootloader which allows programming via UART0 which could be attached to a RS232 port, a UART to USB chip, or whatever you want.  There is a pin that needs to be held low at during reset to get into the on chip bootloader.  [See the user manual for more details.](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/pdf/user.manual.lpc17xx.pdf)